# Using a symfony generated session as an express session?

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, session, cookies

Inside PHP/Symfony I am using Redis sessions to generate a user session.

Inside node.js I want to pull in that session from the session store.

```
var redisSessionClient = redis.createClient({host:'redis://127.0.0.1/0'});
var sessionStore = new RedisStore({prefix: 'my_session', client: redisSessionClient});

app.use(session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: secrets.sessionSecret,
  store: sessionStore
}));
```

Now inside my route I can inspect `req.headers.cookie` and get the session ID by looking at the cookie.

But I want to authenticate users on certain routes, so I need to look at the `req.session` to see if it matches, but express is not giving me any redis session information even though I passed in the `express-session` to the `RedisStore`

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
```

So ultimately I want to check if the user using the node.js features is authenticated to the core system built on Symfony.

**EDIT**

So I see two cookies are generated one is a `connect.sid` and one is `PHPSESSID`

`console.log(req.session)` returns the `connect.sid`

[image]